# How to split row data into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have data like this:

```
ColumA
A1:Data1 A2:Data2 A3:Data3
A1:Data4 A2:Data5 A3:Data6
```

I want to produce output like this:

```
A1        A2        A3
Data1     Data2     Data3
Data4     Data5     Data6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot` To use rows as a column Here is one interesting Link [Refer This](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @T table
(
  ColumnA varchar(50)
)

insert into @T values
('A1:Data1 A2:Data2 A3:Data3'),
('A1:Data4 A2:Data5 A3:Data6')

select substring(ColumnA, Pos.A1+3, Pos.A2-Pos.A1-3) as A1,
       substring(ColumnA, Pos.A2+3, Pos.A3-Pos.A2-3) as A2,
       substring(ColumnA, Pos.A3+3, Pos.AX-Pos.A3-3) as A3
from @T as T
  cross apply (select charindex('A1:', ColumnA) as A1,
                      charindex('A2:', ColumnA) as A2,
                      charindex('A3:', ColumnA) as A3,
                      len(ColumnA)+1            as AX) as Pos
```